# Trying to see if webpage has any differences

Tags: python, json, string, keyerror

This is the webpage: https://www.huobi.com/p/api/contents/

I am trying to make a python code that will tell me if there are any changes to the title. I am using this code and I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\python.py", line 24, in <module>
    before_set = set(before['title'])
KeyError: 'title'
```

And this is the code that I am trying to use

```
import requests
import json
import smtplib
import time

def build_pair_string(pairs):
    pair_string = ""
    for pair in pairs:
        pair_string += pair + "\n"

    return pair_string

try:
    with open('marketstrex.json', 'r') as current_markets:
        before = json.loads(current_markets.read())
except IOError:
    before = requests.get('https://www.huobi.com/p/api/contents/').json()
    with open('marketstrex.json', 'w') as current_markets:
        current_markets.write(json.dumps(before))
    print("First run... Getting initial market data.")

after = requests.get('https://www.huobi.com/p/api/contents/').json()

before_set = set(before['title'])
after_set = set(after['title'])

new_set = after_set - before_set

if not new_set:
    print("No change... Exiting.")
    time.sleep(5)
if new_set:
    with open('marketstrex.json', 'w') as current_markets:
        current_markets.write(json.dumps(after))
    print('Huobi changes:')
    new_list = []
    for pair in new_set:
        new_list.append(pair)  # = [item for item in pair]
    print(new_list)

    sender = 'example@example.com'
    receivers = ['example@example.com']

    message = """
Huobi changes:\n{}\n

    """.format(build_pair_string(new_list))

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com:465')
        smtpObj.login('example@example.com','password')
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
        print("\nSuccessfully sent email")
    except SMTPException:
       print("\nError: unable to send email")
```

it would be able to tell me if there any changes to the webpage but apparently, it doesn't do anything / can't tell if there changes

please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the data shows that there is no `title` in the top-level JSON structure.  There is a `data` element which is a dictionary which contains a `title` element.  Perhaps that's what you want to extract?

The `data` element also contains a member `top_notice_list` which is a list of elements which each have a `title` element.